# Hide div id on screensize

Tags: html, css, mobile, hide

Hi thanks ahead of time I would like to hide a div id on mobile & create a minimum screen size. Anything smaller than 997px width is where I would like to hide the div id.

My CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 997px) {
    #DIV_1 { display:none; }
}
#DIV_1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    cursor: default;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 222px;
    perspective-origin: 111px 279.5px;
    transform-origin: 111px 279.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 30px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_1*/
```

Here is the link
https://www.superherodigital.com/services/graphic-design/

The gray sidebar is the DIV_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently using `min-device-width: 997px` which means that `#div_1` should be hidden if the screen size is larger than `997px`. You should instead use `(max-width : 997px)` and the `@media-query` should be placed in the end of your stylesheet.

Add this code to your stylesheet:

```
#DIV_1 {
     display: block;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
     cursor: default;
     height: auto;
     position: relative;
     width: 222px;
     perspective-origin: 111px 279.5px;
     transform-origin: 111px 279.5px;
     border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
     font: normal normal normal normal 16px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     margin: 0px 0px 30px;
     outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;

@media (max-width : 997px) {
     #DIV_1 { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: @nick_Carlos You're welcome. Please mark my answer as the correct one so that users can know that your query has been answered. Thank you.